# Streaming stdout to a web page

Tags: http, lua, cgi, stdout, luvit

This seems like it should be a really simple thing to achieve, unfortunately web development was never my strong point.

I have a bunch of scripts, and I would like to launch them from a webpage and see the realtime stdout text on the page. Some of the scripts take a long time to run so the normal single response isn't good enough (I have this working already).

As far as I can see, my options are

- stdout to a file, and periodically (every couple of seconds) send a request from the client and respond with the contents of this file.
- Chunked HTTP responses? I'm not sure if this is what they are used for- I tried to implement this already but I think I may be misunderstanding their purpose.
- Websockets (I'm using a Luvit server so this isn't an option).
- ... Something else?

I'm sure there must be a standard way of achieving, I see other sites doing this all the time. Teamcity for example. Or chat rooms (vanilla TCP sockets?).

Any pointers in the right direction appreciated. Simplest method possible, if that's just sending lots of scheduled requests from the client then so be it.

Comment: Does it need to scale in any way? Used by one users in parallel, not like  1000, I assume?

Comment: How is this related to Lua?

Comment: I'm using Luvit, and would like a pure lua solution if possible- I'm currently looking at a lua websockets implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That heavily reminds me of [Common Gateway Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface).

Your own ideas sound all like the right direction. As you are using a shell script, and some potentially nontrivial interactions with the web server, I feel it could make sense to point out where to dig for examples of this kind of code, which was common a long time ago, and very error-prone, basically allways.

Practically, your script is a CGI script, doing typical things.

In the earlier days and years of the internet, that was the "normal way" to implement web page that are not just static files (HTML or others).
The page is basically implemented as a shell script (or any other programm reading from stdin and writing to stdout).

Part of what you are doing/proposing is very similar, and I think there are useful lessons to learn from old CGI code.
For example, getting buffering right with from inside the script over sdtout, whrough the web server onto the client's page can be tricky of course.
So digging out old examples could help a lot.

*(Much of this may be obvious to you, the OP, personally, so take the "you" as potential reader)*
The tricky part in general will be the buffering, I expect. If you are used to explicitly handling stdin/out buffers in shell, for programms that do not support it, the kind of things to expect can be imagined - but if not used to it: I remember CGI is worse, as you have to get the buffering of the HTTP server in sync too (let's hope it is handled automatically) - so maybe start to ask questions/dig for examples early.

The CGI style way would be exactly what you have implemented now - and it the buffering is right, that should be as real-time as it can get. But I understand that you get timeouts because of the long runtime? Or do you have strongly varying runtimes?

In terms of getting it as real-time as possible, there is nothing better than writing stdout to the http stream.
(I assume we accept the overhead of going through a HTTP server.)
Also, I'm thinking of line buffering, so not flushing every char - is that good enough for the use case? (i.e. no animated progress indicator lines/ ANSI escapes that you want to see in real time)
Then maybe the best is to work aroung the issues like timeouts, but to keep the concept. If real time is not that important, other ways may be better in many ways, of course. One point would be that other methods could be required for any scalability.

Comment: Executing the script isn't the problem- continuously streaming some updates to a page as the result of one request is...

Comment: Sort of- thank you for taking the time. I'm still stuck on "In terms of getting it as real-time as possible, there is nothing better than writing stdout to the http stream.". What stream? I thought HTTP was a request - response model?

Comment: @Sam Sure it is, and that is implemented over TCP/IP, a stream. Just like you show structured, readable output on the terminal using the underlying stream stdout. And for your purpose, you want to ideally just push your stdout through the TCP/IP connection unchanged. Except for things like that you can not really push in that direction actively, in HTTP. So an aproach to solve it would be to implement support/"find hacks" to make it possible in HTTP. That needs things like your ideas listed in the question. Plus getting the buffering right, (or at least not hang).

Comment: (You should read to understand the relation of HTTP to the stream used below first, I think.)