# How to redirect STDOUT to sinatra webpage

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra, stdout

I have seen this question asked before, but I am curious as to accomplish this using sinatra.  Recognizing that [sinatra already has a streaming method](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Streaming%20Responses), I assume the solution is already 80% complete.

These are some similiar questions for reference:

Generic redirect stdout:
[Streaming stdout to a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238469/streaming-stdout-to-a-web-page)

Using sinatra to stream stdout (not working for me):
[Sinatra 1.3 Streaming w/ Ruby stdout redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621530/sinatra-1-3-streaming-w-ruby-stdout-redirection)

Here's an example of what I am trying to accomplish(simplified for clarity):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'thin'

get '/' do
  stream do |out|
    out << method_that_puts
  end
end

def method_that_puts
  puts 'I would like...'
  sleep 1.0
  puts 'to display this...'
  sleep 1.0
  puts 'on a web page!'
end
```

**EDIT:** The perfect example of this is travis-ci which is [also built with sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/wild.html).  They are redirecting stdout to the build page... How is this possible?

[image: Travis-CI build page]

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the help so far, I have a halfway solution working. I am currently saving `$stdout` to a new instance of `StringIO` and displaying it afterwards.  BUT, this isn't the answer.  For long running scripts (ie. travis-ci build) it would be ridiculous to wait for entire script to complete then display the `$stdout`.  Need to figure out how to stream it as it comes...

Here's what I have so far:

```
foo = StringIO.new
$stdout = foo

get '/' do
  stream do |out|
    method_that_puts
    out.puts $stdout.string
  end
end

def method_that_puts
  puts 'I would like...'
  sleep 1.0
  puts 'to display this...'
  sleep 1.0
  puts 'on a web page!'
end
```

Comment: Ruby Sinatra is server side, meaning you can't just update the page like that without refreshing. Either you refresh, or you can utilize client-side JavaScript or jQuery, which is easier than you'd think. Also, to direct output to a webpage, you have to embed the value into an *.erb file and run the WEBrick server or use a host.

Comment: You sure it's not possible?  My impression was a stream could be handled for a specific route and continues to 'load' while there is still data in the stream.  There's no refresh -- it's the initial loading of the page.

Comment: Capture the output and provide it as a view value.

Comment: Is it possible to do that in real time? I thought perhaps saving `$stdout` to a variable and passing to a view, but it doesn't show `method_that_pus` concurrently.

Comment: There is, to my knowledge, no such way to accomplish what you want to accomplish, due to Ruby Sinatra being server-side. If you want things to update, use client-side Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Sinatra::Streaming`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/streaming.html) (from the `sinatra-contrib` gem), which provides an output object you can write to.

Here's the example from the docs:

```
get '/' do
  stream do |out|
    out.puts "Hello World!", "How are you?"
    out.write "Written #{out.pos} bytes so far!\n"
    out.putc(65) unless out.closed?
    out.flush
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice.  This is definitely in the right direction.  I still can't figure out how to puts out the output of `method_that_puts` though.  `out.method_that_puts` just puts out what was returned -- `nil`.

Comment: The bad idea would be `$stdout = out`, which would redirect all `puts` output to your response. My real suggestion is to simply pass `out` to `method_that_puts`, and use it there.

Comment: That makes sense. Here's my confusion -- wouldn't that require me to make my own method to pass in the args?  I'm using gems I don't own.  For example, I'm trying to embed Sinatra server log to page.

Comment: If you're piping the log, maybe stealing `$stderr` isn't totally crazy. I would try [`file-tail`](https://github.com/flori/file-tail) to tail your file through to the streaming response, or you could [set up the logger](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/middleware/rack_commonlogger) with a shared I/O object that the action can consume.